# Shell script works fine while run separately but fails while scheduling in cron job

Tags: shell, unix, cron, ksh

I have  a script which runs perfectly fine while it is run in the shell.

But runs incompletely or partially while the same script is scheduled in cron job.
It gets terminated abruptly

I have scheduled the cron job to run every 15mins.

Here is the code for the cronjob.

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /home/convteam/Conversion/update_revenue/RunUpdateRevenue.ksh > /home/convteam/Conversion/update_revenue/RunUpdateRevenue.log
```

I'm scheduling the job using a user called as 'convteam' and not as a root.

Can you help me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Bash has an `-x` option that prints debug info as the script is executing. Check if ksh has something similar. Then, add `2>&1` to the command line, and observe the `RunUpdateRevenue.log`.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov - I would assume from the filename that the OP isn't using bash.  It would be good to check whether ksh has a similar option.

Comment: @ghoti That is exactly what I said. I just checked the `ksh` manpage though, and it seems to have the same feature via `set -x`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recurring issue.  The most common reasons for cron jobs failing are:

1. Assumptions about relative file paths - use full absolute filenames throughout
2. Assumptions about the environment.  You should "source" start-up files that you rely on, typically (for ksh):

   ```
   . /etc/profile
   . ~/.profile
   . "$ENV"
   ```

`$ENV` is optional, but when used usually has the value `~/.kshrc`.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: Reference to the profile file in the script resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

crontab invokes shell in an non-login, non-interactive mode. Bash shell in this mode does not load the usual startup files such as /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, which may loose some important environment varible definations like PATH.

You may solve your problem by sourcing particular startup files (/etc/profile, ~/.profile in ksh if they exist and are readable) before run ksh script when runing in crontab. you can "man ksh" to see the details of ksh startup process.